# Update MYSQL Database Bewteen Two Dates

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sql-update

I am having trouble getting this to work, I need to update a table in my database, changing one of the fields for all records that fall in between two dates and have a certain user name.

The date values are being passed to a script from a form.

What I have:

```
mysql_query("
    UPDATE data 
    SET status='Submitted' 
    WHERE (user_name = '$current_user->user_login') 
    AND labor_date >= '$_POST[start]' 
    AND labor_date <= '$_POST[end]'")
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

L

Comment: Do you have any error messages / logs? Please provide more information. Additionally, please provide information about your date format. This could be a reason, as your query looks fine, at a first glance. Formats like e.g. `1950-01-25` should work. Also be aware of SQL injection attacks, as you write that your dates come from a form.

Comment: Error message, example data, table structure? heard of SQL injection?

Comment: $_POST[start],$_POST[end] are they in the right format

Comment: ^ should start and end not be in quotes?

Comment: Use MYSQL BETWEEN instead of >= and <=

Comment: can you put brackets around the variables in your query?  just so i feel better?  `'{$current_user->user_login}'` and `'{$_POST['start']}'` and `'{$_POST['end']}'`

Comment: @Lawrence . . . Print out the statement after variable substitution to see what it looks like.  If the problem isn't immediately obvious, then edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your dates are in the format:

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

You can also check mysql_affected_rows() to see if the query is running successfully but finding no rows that match the criteria.

You might also want to build the string as a variable like $sql = "…";

This would allow you to echo it out for debugging purposes.

*You do realize that mysql_ is a deprecated library and will soon be removed entirely from PHP? You should be using mysqli or PDO at this point.*

Oh yeah, one little tip on interpolation of arrays with keys:

```
AND labor_date >= '{$_POST['start']}'
```

Comment: I agree with @ewein's comment, i would have used the BETWEEN syntax for this, however that is not the reason for your problem -- just an alternative that's a bit cleaner.